# TBB spin_mutex inside parallel_for to block a critical section

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, tbb, thread-synchronization

Conceptually, how can I block a critical section inside a `tbb::parallel_for` call using `tbb:spin_mutex`? The critical section is less than 20 instructions so `spin_mutex` is ideal. For example the following dummy code explains the situation:

```
function() {
    // I'm using lambda functions in parallel_for call here. The parallel_for 
    // is multithreading across the size of the vector customVec
    tbb::parallel_for(
        tbb::blocked_range<vector<CustomeType>::iterator>(customVec.begin(), customVec.end(), 1), 
        [&](tbb::blocked_range<vector<CustomType>::iterator> customVec) {
            for (vector<CustomType>::iterator it = customVec.begin(); it != customVec.end(); it++) {
                CustomType item = *it;
                ...
                ...

                // This is the cross-functional call that each thread will call
                // critical section is in-side the functionA
                item->functionA(param1, param2);
            }

            ...
            ...   
        }
    );

    ...
    ...
}
```

And functionA:

```
functionA (Type1 param1, Type2 param2) {
    if (conditionX) {
        /* This file read is the critical section. So basically, need to 
        block multiple threads reading the same file to reduce I/O cost
        and redundancy. Since file read can be stored in a global variable
        that can be accessed in memory by other threads */

        fileRead(filename); // Critical line that need to be protected
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

What I'm struggling with is how I can setup `spin_mutex` in `functionA()` so that the `mutex` is shared across the thread and threads won't overstep each other an try to execute the critical section at the same time.

Note: suppose `function()` and `functionA()` belongs to two separate C++ Classes and there are no class-based inheritance between the two classes that have `function()` and `functionA()` as member functions

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider using a static `spin_mutex` inside the function:

```
functionA (Type1 param1, Type2 param2) {
    if (conditionX) {
        /* This file read is the critical section. So basically, need to 
        block multiple threads reading the same file to reduce I/O cost
        and redundancy. Since file read can be stored in a global variable
        that can be accessed in memory by other threads */

        // A static mutex that is shared across all invocations of the function.
        static tbb::spin_mutex mtx;
        // Acquire a lock 
        tbb::spin_mutex::scoped_lock lock(mtx);
        fileRead(filename); // Critical line that need to be protected
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Pay attention that it will work only with C++11 and later (because you need the "magic static", i.e. thread-safeness of static variable initialization).

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution. Might not be the optimal but solved the issue I had. So going to post it as an answer for someone who might run into the same issue.

Basically, the solution is to define `spin_mutex` object outside the `parallel_for` and pass it to the function call as a reference. I have posted the same code example from the question with the solution below:

```
tbb::spin_mutex mtx;   // Declare spin_mutex object
function() {
    // I'm using lambda functions in parallel_for call here. The parallel_for 
    // is multithreading across the size of the vector customVec
    tbb::parallel_for(
        tbb::blocked_range<vector<CustomeType>::iterator>(customVec.begin(), customVec.end(), 1), 
        [&](tbb::blocked_range<vector<CustomType>::iterator> customVec) {
            for (vector<CustomType>::iterator it = customVec.begin(); it != customVec.end(); it++) {
                CustomType item = *it;
                ...
                ...

                // This is the cross-functional call that each thread will call
                // critical section is in-side the functionA
                item->functionA(param1, param2, mtx);   // pass object as a reference
            }

            ...
            ...   
        }
    );

    ...
    ...
}
```

and functionA:

```
// Pass the spin_mutex object by reference
functionA (Type1 param1, Type2 param2, tbb::spin_mutex& mtx) {
    if (conditionX) {
        /* This file read is the critical section. So basically, need to 
        block multiple threads reading the same file to reduce I/O cost
        and redundancy. Since file read can be stored in a global variable
        that can be accessed in memory by other threads */

        // Acquire a scope lock 
        { 
            tbb::spin_mutex::scoped_lock lock(mtx);
            fileRead(filename); // Critical line that need to be protected
        }
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```